# Relationship between CFT coupling constants and gravity parameters in the AdS/CFT correspondence

Tags: string-theory, physical-constants, ads-cft

The AdS/CFT correspondence relates a string theory in AdS to quantum field theory. Various versions of this correspondence exist, and I want to know the map between parameters in the field theory and parameters in the gravity theory.

The string theory on AdS has three parameters: $L_{AdS}$, $G_N$, and $g_s$. The quantum field theory (for $\mathcal N=4$ SYM) has two parameters $g_{YM}$ and $N$. What is the relation between these parameters?

What about the case of ABJM? In this case, what are the parameters on the gravity side, and how are they related to $N$ and $k$? (I guess there are two different regimes where one can ask this question, corresponding to 11d supergravity or 10d supergravity.)

The SYK model is also ("sort-of"?) dual to JT gravity in $d=2$. How does $N$ on the SYK model side relate to the parameters of $JT$ gravity? (I suppose these are $L_{AdS}$ and $G_N$)?

And finally what is the relation between $\Lambda$, $L_{AdS}$, $\alpha$, $g_s$ and $G_N$? (in $d$ dimensions?)

Are there other examples of AdS/CFT where one can ask analogous questions?

The answers to these questions are well-known to experts, but can be confusing given the different dimensionalities of space-time, and units (string-units versus planck units), and it would be nice to see them all together in one place, with comparison between them.

Comment: I wouldn't mind seeing how *"string units"* are defined.  And their relationship to Planck units (or *rationalized* Planck units).